# The Value attribute in spring-boot under Windows and launched from git bash when the string value starts with slash returns the Windows cwd

Tags: windows, bash, git, spring-boot

The Value attribute in spring-boot under Windows and launched from git bash when the string value starts with slash returns the Windows cwd

This is a very silly bug and only shows itself in this specific case of using git bash (which I think is really Cygwin) and Spring-boot, if you start the process from Powershell under Windows or under bash in Linux or WSL2 it does not happen.

You might want a string with a leading slash if you are storing a path to make up a URL on an endpoint. Just beware, because it caught me unawares. It is just convenient to use bash everywhere and not resort to Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer to this is: Just don't do it. But it would be nice to be able to in some circumstances where for other reasons you are stuck with Windows.